# Add text data to specific scatter points that aren't known

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

I have a scatter plot that looks like this:

[image]

I can use the following code to add text from a list to every scatter point:

```
# Add text names to the plot
for i, txt in enumerate(names):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]), alpha=0.6)
```

However I only want to annotate the points that are past `2` on the `x-axis` and above `2` on the `y-axis`. How do I go about doing that? The Matplotlib documentation doesn't give me information on marking specific points unless I already know exactly which ones I want to edit (In this case, I don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are asking to annotate all points after `2` on the `x-axis` and all points after `2` on the `y-axis`. If so, this is the way to do:

```
for i, txt in enumerate(names): 
    if x[i] > 2 or y[i] > 2: 
        # annotate only if a point is having either x > 2 or y > 2.
        ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), alpha=0.6)
```

Comment: Funnily enough that did it! I don't know why I didn't consider it myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking the values of the points before annotating them.

For example

```
for i, txt in enumerate(names):
    if x[i] > 2 and y[i] > 2:
         ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), alpha=0.6)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it only gave me the names for the points to the top-right of the main 'cloud' of points, nowhere else

Comment: Perhaps you are misunderstanding each other in terms of order of operations in the phrase "points that are past 2 on the x-axis and above 2 on the y-axis". Try the condition x[i] > 2 or y[i] instead?

Comment: That did it, don't know why I didn't consider it myself, thanks!